# Memory barriers in DirectX and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to sort out memory barrier functions in DirectX and OpenGL. My ultimate goal is to implement HLSL memory barrier functions in GLSL. I found that documentation for both DX and GL is rather obscure.
There are 6 synchronization routines in HLSL:

- `GroupMemoryBarrier()`
- `GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync()`
- `DeviceMemoryBarrier()`
- `DeviceMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync()`
- `AllMemoryBarrier()`
- `AllMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync()`

It seems like I only truly understand `WithGroupSync` ending which means "block execution of all threads in a group until all of them have reached this call". I am also almost 100% sure that this is what `barrier()` function in GLSL does.

What I am not sure about is what device memory, group memory and all memory means. My current idea is that

- Group memory is group shared memory only
- Device memory is GPU memory (such as textures, buffers)
- All memory is device + group shared memory

What I really don't understand is how this maps to GLSL synchronization functions:

- `groupMemoryBarrier()`. Documentation says: "groupMemoryBarrier waits on the completion of all memory accesses performed by an invocation of a compute shader relative to the same access performed other invocations in the same work group and then returns with no other effect". The main question is:

  - Despite having the same name as the function in HLSL, it seems like this one waits for completion of *all* memory transactions, not only to group shared memory.
- `memoryBarrier()`. Documentation says: "memoryBarrier waits on the completion of all accesses resulting from the use of *image* variables or *atomic counters* and then returns with no other effect. The questions are:

  - Does it really only wait for completion of image and atomic counter memory transactions and ignores buffer and shared memory? (`memoryBarrierBuffer` and `memoryBarrierShared` suggest that there are other type of memory synchronization)
  - What is the difference between `groupMemoryBarrier()` and `memoryBarrier()` in compute shader? I can only imagine that the latter waits for completion of ALL transactions across all threads, which would have huge performance impact and is thus disallowed in HLSL.
- `memoryBarrierBuffer`, `memoryBarrierImage` and `memoryBarrierAtomicCounter`. Documentation says: "memoryBarrier* waits on the completion of all accesses resulting from the use of buffer/image/atomic counter and then returns with no other effect." The questions:

  - I cannot understand if this only relates to threads in one work group or if synchronization is performed across all threads in all work groups

Below is how I understand mapping of HLSL functions to GLSL:

- `GroupMemoryBarrier()` = `groupMemoryBarrier()` + `memoryBarrierShared()`
- `GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync()` = `GroupMemoryBarrier()` + `barrier()`
- `DeviceMemoryBarrier()` = `memoryBarrierBuffer()` + `memoryBarrierImage()` + `memoryBarrierAtomicCounter()`
- `DeviceMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync()` = `DeviceMemoryBarrier()` + `barrier()`
- `AllMemoryBarrier()` = all barrier functions
- `AllMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync()` = `AllMemoryBarrier()` + `barrier()`

I would greatly appreciate any help in sorting out this matter.